# PDFSharp Export JPG - ASP.NET

Tags: vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, pdfsharp

I am using an ajaxfileupload control to upload a pdf file to the server.  On the server side, I'd like to convert the pdf to jpg.  Using the [PDFsharp Sample: Export Images](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/ExportImages-sample.ashx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) as a guide, I've got the following:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports PdfSharp.Pdf
Imports System.IO
Imports PdfSharp.Pdf.IO
Imports PdfSharp.Pdf.Advanced

Namespace Tools

Public Module ConvertImage

Public Sub pdf2JPG(pdfFile As String, jpgFile As String)

        pdfFile = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath & "upload\" & pdfFile

        Dim document As PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument = PdfReader.Open(pdfFile)

        Dim imageCount As Integer = 0
        ' Iterate pages
        For Each page As PdfPage In document.Pages
            ' Get resources dictionary
            Dim resources As PdfDictionary = page.Elements.GetDictionary("/Resources")
            If resources IsNot Nothing Then
                ' Get external objects dictionary
                Dim xObjects As PdfDictionary = resources.Elements.GetDictionary("/XObject")
                If xObjects IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim items As ICollection(Of PdfItem) = xObjects.Elements.Values
                    ' Iterate references to external objects
                    For Each item As PdfItem In items
                        Dim reference As PdfReference = TryCast(item, PdfReference)
                        If reference IsNot Nothing Then
                            Dim xObject As PdfDictionary = TryCast(reference.Value, PdfDictionary)
                            ' Is external object an image?
                            If xObject IsNot Nothing AndAlso xObject.Elements.GetString("/Subtype") = "/Image" Then
                                ExportImage(xObject, imageCount)
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub ExportImage(image As PdfDictionary, ByRef count As Integer)
        Dim filter As String = image.Elements.GetName("/Filter")
        Select Case filter
            Case "/DCTDecode"
                ExportJpegImage(image, count)
                Exit Select

            Case "/FlateDecode"
                ExportAsPngImage(image, count)
                Exit Select
        End Select
    End Sub

    Private Sub ExportJpegImage(image As PdfDictionary, ByRef count As Integer)
        ' Fortunately JPEG has native support in PDF and exporting an image is just writing the stream to a file.
        Dim stream As Byte() = image.Stream.Value
        Dim fs As New FileStream([String].Format("Image{0}.jpeg", System.Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(count), count - 1)), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
        Dim bw As New BinaryWriter(fs)
        bw.Write(stream)
        bw.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ExportAsPngImage(image As PdfDictionary, ByRef count As Integer)
        Dim width As Integer = image.Elements.GetInteger(PdfImage.Keys.Width)
        Dim height As Integer = image.Elements.GetInteger(PdfImage.Keys.Height)
        Dim bitsPerComponent As Integer = image.Elements.GetInteger(PdfImage.Keys.BitsPerComponent)

        ' TODO: You can put the code here that converts vom PDF internal image format to a Windows bitmap
        ' and use GDI+ to save it in PNG format.
        ' It is the work of a day or two for the most important formats. Take a look at the file
        ' PdfSharp.Pdf.Advanced/PdfImage.cs to see how we create the PDF image formats.
        ' We don't need that feature at the moment and therefore will not implement it.
        ' If you write the code for exporting images I would be pleased to publish it in a future release
        ' of PDFsharp.
    End Sub

End Module

End Namespace
```

As I debug, it blows up on `Dim filter As String = image.Elements.GetName("/Filter")` in ExportImage.  The message is:

> Unhandled exception at line 336, column 21 in ~:46138/ScriptResource.axd?d=LGq0ri4wlMGBKd-1vxLjtxNH_pd26HaruaEG_1eWx-epwPmhNKVpO8IpfHoIHzVj2Arxn5804quRprX3HtHb0OmkZFRocFIG-7a-SJYT_EwYUd--x9AHktpraSBgoZk4VJ1RMtFNwl1mULDLid5o5U9iBcuDi4EQpbpswgBn_oI1&t=ffffffffda74082d
>   0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: error raising upload complete event and start new upload

Any thoughts on what the issue might be?  It seems an issue with the ajaxfileupload control, but I don't understand why it would be barking here.  It's neither here nor there, but I know I'm not using jpgFile yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDFsharp cannot create JPEG Images from PDF pages:
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/PDFsharpFAQ.ashx#Can_PDFsharp_show_PDF_files_Print_PDF_files_Create_images_from_PDF_files_3

The sample you refer to can extract JPEG Images that are included in PDF files. That's all. The sample does not cover all possible cases.

Long story short: the code you are showing seems unrelated to the error message. And it seems unrelated to your intended goal.

Comment: The page states "The [PDFsharp Samples] (http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/PDFsharpSamples.ashx) show how to invoke Adobe Reader or Acrobat to view or print PDF files and how to invoke GhostScript to create images from PDF pages."  Thoughts as to which sample is showing how to invoke GhostScript to create images from PDF pages?

Comment: There are samples for Adobe Reader and GhostScript. I don't remember if they are included with the latest version. So also download the older source packages (1.31, 1.30, ...) until you find the samples. Pay attention to the license conditions of GhostScript if you intend to use that.